# How can I get Copyright, Version, Company, etc. from within a .Net Core console app?

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to find a was to read Package properties like Copyright, Version, Company, etc. from within a .NET Core console app.  This used to be simple using Framework with attributes like AssemblyCopyrightAttribute but with Core I have a clue.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what're you trying to use this for? This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What's your _end goal_ that you're trying to accomplish with this information?

Comment: The same information is in the assemblies after compilation, so I wonder why you cannot use the previous approach (though you might have to be on .NET Core 2.0, which contains the necessary classes).

Comment: They are embedded as *unmanaged* resources in the executable file.  Highly specific to Windows, so not an ideal feature in .NETCore.  There is a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo/) that adds it back, I suspect you'll have to test on the *nixes to verify it still works.  Consider using Reflection instead.

Comment: I'm using the functionality to find the LocalPath on my machine to store configuration data plus to show the program title and current version in the window titlebar.

Comment: I thought of FileVersionInfo, too, but I don't want to examine the .exe file.  Rather, 'from WITHIN the .exe I want to get at the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FileVersionInfo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo/) as below

```
var fileVersionInfo = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
Console.WriteLine(fileVersionInfo.ProductVersion); // Package Version
Console.WriteLine(fileVersionInfo.CompanyName); // Company
Console.WriteLine(fileVersionInfo.LegalCopyright); // Copyright
Console.WriteLine(fileVersionInfo.Comments); // Description
```